# Binding against enums with valueconverter doesn't show text

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm trying to bind an enum to a RadioGroup but the text doesn't show up in the caption.  What am I missing?

My ViewModel has the following:

```
    private List<Incident.Agent> _agentList = new List<Incident.Agent>
    {
        Incident.Agent.Uxo, Incident.Agent.Mine, Incident.Agent.Other
    };

    public List<Incident.Agent> AgentList
    {
        get { return _agentList; }
        set
        {
            _agentList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => AgentList);
        }
    }

    private Incident.Agent _agent;

    public Incident.Agent IncidentAgent
    {
        get { return _agent; }
        set
        {
            _agent = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IncidentAgent);
        }
    }
```

And my axml has:

```
    <Mvx.MvxRadioGroup
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_radio"
      local:MvxBind="ItemsSource AgentList, Converter=IncidentAgent; SelectedItem IncidentAgent, Converter=IncidentAgent" />
```

Item_Radio.axml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      local:MvxBind="Text" />
```

The value converter is:

```
public sealed class IncidentAgentValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<Incident.Agent, string>
{
    protected override string Convert(Incident.Agent value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case Incident.Agent.Mine:
                return "Mine";
            case Incident.Agent.Uxo:
                return "UXO";
            case Incident.Agent.Other:
                return "Other";
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Can't convert Incident.Agent from {0}", value));
    }

    protected override Incident.Agent ConvertBack(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case "Mine":
                return Incident.Agent.Mine;
            case "UXO":
                return Incident.Agent.Uxo;
            case "Other":
                return Incident.Agent.Other;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Can't convert Incident.Agent from '{0}'", value));
    }
}
```

With the above I don't see any text or check buttons.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's the same thing as this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23706333/1630816  The solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code includes `ItemsSource AgentList, Converter=IncidentAgent;` - which tries to apply the IncidentAgent converter to a list.

Try applying the converter within the template instead - exactly as is done in the sample you reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23706333/1630816